# Disappearing ChangeableText

Tags: android, andengine

I have a problem. When i create a changeable text then some letters disappears. I tried with sever fonts and it's not changing!

Piece of code:

FONT:

```
FontFactory.setAssetBasePath("font/");
this.mFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```

And the changeabletext:

```
ChangeableText ty = new ChangeableText(20, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2 - 80, mFont, "Game over!");
this.mScene.attachChild(ty);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had it when the `BitmapTextureAtlas` was too small. Try making it larger (Maybe 512x512), it also depends on the font size.